# Salesforce to Salesforce authentication using JWT

Tags: apexrest, jwt

I created a self signed certificate in my dev org A and exported the certificate to keystore. Now I want to use that certificate and import it in Org B to enable JWT authentication. But I get the error saying :

Data Not Available
The data you were trying to access could not be found. It may be due to another user deleting the data or a system error. If you know the data is not deleted but cannot access it, please look at our support page.

Is there any set up I am missing or any other way to implement JWT Authetication?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a self signed certificate in client org and then include that certificate in the connected app in the server org.